# gtest documentation using Doxygen on custom annotations

Tags: doxygen, googletest

I am looking for the auto generation of my unit tests documentation. Specifically, I would like to use doxygen on my c++ project that scans it and looks for unit tests implemented in gtest (TEST/TEST_F/TEST_P macros) with my custom annotations  : @description, @entry_criteria, @exit_criteria and generates a single text/json file that contains all test names together with their annotations.

In my environment there is DOXYGEN version 1.8.13 installed (so it doesn't support JSON unfortunately). Also, I have tried following `Doxyfile` :

```
# Project settings
PROJECT_NAME = Memory-unit-tests
PROJECT_NUMBER = 1.0

# Output directory
OUTPUT_DIRECTORY = ./unit-tests-docs

# Documentation format options
OUTPUT_LANGUAGE        = English
BRIEF_MEMBER_DESC      = YES
REPEAT_BRIEF           = YES
GENERATE_XML           = NO
GENERATE_HTML          = NO
GENERATE_LATEX         = NO
GENERATE_MAN           = YES
MAN_OUTPUT             = manpages

# Configuration options related to the input files
INPUT                  =
INPUT_ENCODING         = UTF-8
FILE_PATTERNS          = *.cpp \
                         *.h
RECURSIVE              = YES

# Configuration options related to warning and progress messages
QUIET                  = NO
WARNINGS               = YES
WARN_IF_UNDOCUMENTED   = YES
WARN_IF_DOC_ERROR      = YES
WARN_NO_PARAMDOC       = NO
WARN_AS_ERROR          = NO
WARN_FORMAT            = "$file:$line: $text"


# Preprocessing options
ENABLE_PREPROCESSING = YES
MACRO_EXPANSION = YES
EXPAND_ONLY_PREDEF = YES
EXPAND_AS_DEFINED = TEST(TEST_F,TEST_P)

# Test annotations
ALIASES += "description=@par Description:"
ALIASES += "entry_criteria=@par Entry Criteria:"
ALIASES += "exit_criteria=@par Exit Criteria:"

# Other configuration options (customize as needed)

# Exclude directories or files

# Additional configuration options...
```

But I can not achieve what I am looking for :( . Any advice, on how can I achieve this?

Comment: First of all doxygen version 1.8.13 is quite old  (December 29,2016), the current doxygen version is 1.9.7 so you should definitely update.  Regarding JSON what should it do, looks like it is just a layer that should call doxygen.

Comment: @albert it should just create a text file that contains a list of all tests with their annotations

Comment: Not sure whether doxygen is here the right tool, maybe just a small grep / awk  / sed script will do. Doxygen cannot export plain text or JSON, but probably you could post-process the XML output (see setting `GENERATE_XML`) to get the desirec result.